# SQL Where Condition About Range Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

I have two tables like this,

```
create table tblCard(
Start_Id int,
End_Id int,
Card_Name varchar(100))

create table tblVisitor(
Card_Id int,
Visitor_Name varchar(150)
)

insert into tblCard values (1,50,'Engineer')
insert into tblCard values (51,100,'Helper')
insert into tblCard values (101,200,'Employeer')

insert into tblVisitor values (23,'PersonA')
insert into tblVisitor values (53,'PersonB')
insert into tblVisitor values (101,'PersonC')


select V.Card_Id,V.Visitor_Name,C.Card_Name from tblVisitor V join tblCard C on **??**
```

What should I syntax for question marked place

Firstly I think case when conditions one by one but maybe there is exists easier way Could you help me about this situation.

Comment: Cardid between start_id and end_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, is this your expected result.

```
SELECT V.Card_Id, V.Visitor_Name, C.Card_Name
FROM tblVisitor AS V
INNER JOIN tblCard AS C ON V.Card_Id BETWEEN C.Start_Id AND C.End_Id
```